# ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140.dll or msvcp140_1.dll'. Even when the files are located in the %PATH% directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, dll, appdata

I receive the following error when importing tensorflow

```
(base) PS C:\Users\Rostyslav\GIt\GNN-GCP> python run_model.py --train --save
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_model.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 54, in preload_check
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140.dll or msvcp140_1.dll'. TensorFlow requires that these DLLs be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. You may install these DLLs by downloading "Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" for your platform from this URL: https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
```

even when I have both `msvcp140.dll` and `msvcp140_1.dll` installed and they are both placed in the directory specified by %PATH% environment variable

```
C:\Users\Rostyslav>where msvcp140.dll
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin\msvcp140.dll
C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll
C:\Users\Rostyslav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\msvcp140.dll <-- HERE
C:\Users\Rostyslav\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\msvcp140.dll
```

My path environmental variable looks like this:

[image]

After searching, I found that the reason can be in incompatibility between `protobuf`, `tensorflow`, and `python`. I have tried many different combinations of versions, but all of them lead to the same error.
The current versions are as follows:

```
tensorflow                2.5.0
python                    3.8.10
protobuf                  3.17.3
```

If you need any additional information, please let me know, and I will share. Any help is appreciated because I tackle this problem the whole day.
Thank you!

Update:

After I modify `self_check.py` to show more detailed information about the error, this is what I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 50, in preload_check
    ctypes.WinDLL(dll_name)
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 381, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 50, in preload_check
    ctypes.WinDLL(dll_name)
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 381, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_model.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\Rostyslav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 55, in preload_check
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140.dll or msvcp140_1.dll'. TensorFlow requires that these DLLs be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. You may install these DLLs by downloading "Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" for your platform from this URL: https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
```

The list of my installed packages

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
argon2-cffi               20.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
async-generator           1.10                     pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     21.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
bleach                    3.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2021.7.5             haa95532_1
cachetools                4.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2021.5.30        py36haa95532_0
cffi                      1.14.6                   pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        2.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
cpuonly                   1.0                           0    pytorch
dataclasses               0.8                      pypi_0    pypi
debugpy                   1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 5.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
defusedxml                0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.3                      pypi_0    pypi
flatbuffers               1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               1.33.1                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.34.1                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.2                      pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        3.7.3                    pypi_0    pypi
ipykernel                 6.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   7.25.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython-genutils          0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipywidgets                7.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
jinja2                    3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter                   1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-client            6.1.12                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-console           6.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-pygments       0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-widgets        1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-nightly             2.5.0.dev2021032900          pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
markdown                  3.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
nbclient                  0.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 6.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbformat                  5.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
nest-asyncio              1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  6.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.19.5                   pypi_0    pypi
oauthlib                  3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1k               h2bbff1b_0
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 21.0                     pypi_0    pypi
pandocfilters             1.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pickleshare               0.7.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    8.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       20.0.2                   py36_3
prometheus-client         0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            3.0.19                   pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.20                     pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 2.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.6.8                h9f7ef89_7
python-dateutil           2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pywin32                   301                      pypi_0    pypi
pywinpty                  1.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     22.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
qtconsole                 5.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
qtpy                      1.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.26.0                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                52.0.0           py36haa95532_0
six                       1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.36.0               h2bbff1b_0
tensorboard               2.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
testpath                  0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
torch                     1.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
torchaudio                0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.1                      pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3                  pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.26.6                   pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wcwidth                   0.2.5                    pypi_0    pypi
webencodings              0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
wrapt                     1.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
zipp                      3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Comment: You could temporarily modify tensorflow's "self_check.py". In "preload_check" in the "except OSError:" handler you can add a line "import traceback; traceback.print_exc()". This should show a more detailed error information about what wents wrong on import.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you! I have modified "self_check.py" and updated the thread. Do you know, what can be wrong?

Comment: Tensorflow requires [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0) on Windows 7 or later (64-bit) machine. Follow the steps mentioned on [Tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows_1) for windows machine, use virtual environment to install. Thanks!

Comment: @TFer thanks for the answer! I have Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 installed and I also installed tensorflow properly, but the issue still remains... I guess it boils down to the conflicts in the packages that I have, but I cannot manage to find it. Could you help me with it? I have listed all of the packages I have in the update of the question

Comment: Solved! The reason was in the incompatibility of  tensorflow with some packages and Python. To solve, I have removed the whole environment completely and installed Python 3.6.8 and tensorflow 2.0.0.

Answer (score -1):

Solved - I had same issue and downloaded that folder given in the link but didn't work. And I **search**ed from internet '**Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable'** , **download**ed .x64 file from this link: **https://www.comss.ru/page.php?id=6172.**

[img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QveyI.png)

[img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmL44.png)

**Restart**ed computer and **Problem is solved**