# Python, installed two different versions?

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda

I am struggling with the incompatibility of my version of python with some packages. At the moment I am confused with the following:
when I check the version of python via conda I get :

```
python                    3.8.10               hdbf39b2_7
```

but when I check it via cmd:

```
C:\Users\name>python --version
Python 3.9.1
```

which indicates two different versions. Is it OK? If it is possible to answer, tell me please what is the reason and whether it can cause incompatibility problems.

Thank you!

Comment: This is usually not a problem as long as you keep this in mind and know which version executes your code and which libraries are installed for which version (virtual environments can help).

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you! If you can, would you take a look at another problem I have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68520553/importerror-could-not-find-the-dlls-msvcp140-dll-or-msvcp140-1-dll-even-wh ? Sorry for off-topic, but I would widely appreciate if you could share your thoughts on it.

Comment: You have installed two version. You can uninstall one of them to resolve problem.

Comment: on Linux I have installed different versions because some modules works with older version and you have to wait until they create version for newer Python. But when I install new Python then it automatically creates programs `python3.8`, `python3.9`, `python3.10` and even `python2.7` - so I have no problem to use correct version. And the same is with `pip3.8`, `pip3.9`, `pin3,10` and `pip2.7` - so I have no problem to install module for correct Python.

Comment: In Linux I can also add `shebang` in first line - i.e. `#!/usr/bin/env python3.8` - and set script as executable and system will run it like any other program (by clicking) and it will use this `shebang` to run it with correct version.